# How to allow visitors click on "Desktop View" when htaccess send them in mobile view?

Tags: php, .htaccess

When people visit my domain.com they are redirected with htaccess to domain.com/m that is the mobile version.
However, I want to have a "return to desktop view" also.

My question is how can I do it, if the htaccess send me back to the mobile version ?

Comment: Have you tried putting the mobile/non-mobile check at the php level? that would let you set a session variable for mobile/desktop version preference

Comment: @ford No I didn't. I do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that one simple way to do this would be to make a php session variable that is set when the user first opts into the desktop version of the site.

When the user clicks the 'return to desktop view link', execute a function like this one:

```
function force_desktop_mode () {
  if (!isset($_SESSION['desktop'])) {
    $_SESSION['desktop'] = true;
  }
}
```

Then, at the beginning of the page (in mobile view, when user is freshly redirected to mobile site)

```
if ($_SESSTION['desktop']) {
  // redirect to nonmobile version of the site
}
```

check the [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) for some additional examples on how to use session variables.